# corona sdk xScale in transition.to

Tags: lua, coronasdk, xscale

How to make object big by `xScale` in `transition.to` for a period of time this is my line code

```
 transition.to(object, {time = 200, radius = 3, alpha = 1, xScale = 1.4, yScale = 1})
```

let's say I want this happen for 5 seconds then return to the default size `xscale =1` and `yscale = 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `delay` parameter to begin the second transition after x miliseconds. Look at docs: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/transition/to.html

```
transition.to(object,{time=200,radius=3,alpha=1,xScale=1.4,yScale=1}) 
transition.to(object,{time=200,radius=3,alpha=1,xScale=1,yScale=1, delay=5000})
```

Comment: Hi @user3575739 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.